# Zend creating forms based on requests within one controller/action

Tags: zend-framework, request, zend-form

I don't really know how to word the title well, but here's my issue. I decided instead of having 25 controllers to handle pages, I have one `PageController` with a `viewAction` that takes in a `:page` parameter - for example, `http://localhost/website/page/about-us` would direct to `PageController::viewAction()` with a parameter of `page = about-us`. All of the pages are stored in a templates folder, so the viewrenderer is set to render `application\templates\default\about-us.phtml`.

I did this so I can consolidate and it seemed like a better approach. My question is the following: lets say when the page request is `contact-us`, I would need a `Zend_Form` to be used within the contact page. So, I would need a way within `PageController::viewAction()` to recognize that the page needs to have a form built, build the form, and also upon submission the need to process it (maybe this should be handled in an abstract process method - not sure).

I have no idea how to implement this. I thought maybe I can store a column with the name of a form and a connecting page identifier. Even better, create a one-to-many page to forms, and then in the submission loop through the forms and check if submitted and if so then process it (maybe there is a `isSubmitted()` method within zend_form. I really don't know how to handle this, and am looking for any help i can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that came to mind that may work or help point you in a direction that works for you.

This may only work well assuming you were to have no more than one form per page, if you need more than one form on a page, you would have to do something beyond this automatic form handling.

Create a standard location for forms that are attached to pages (e.g. application/forms/page).  This is where the automatic forms associated with pages will be kept.

In your `viewAction`, you could take advantage of the autoloader to see if a form for that page exists.  For example:

```
$page  = $this->getParam('page');
$page  = ucfirst(preg_replace('/-(\w)/ie', "strtoupper('$1')", $page)); // contact-us -> ContactUs
$class = 'Application_Form_Page_' . $page;

// class_exists will invoke the autoloader to map a class to a file
if (class_exists($class)) {
    // a form is defined for this page
    $form = new $class();

    // check if form was posted
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            // form is valid - determine how to process it
        }
    }

    // assign the form to the view
    $this->view->pageForm = $form;
}
```

All this really leaves out is the action you take to process a specific form.  Since the contact form will likely generate an email, and another form may insert data into a database, you will need some sort of callback system or perhaps another class that can be mapped automatically which contains the form processor code.

Anyway something along those lines is what came to mind first, I hope that helps give you some more ideas.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'll look into this over the weekend. You're absolutely right though, it wouldnt be a plausable answer when more than one form is needed, and I tend to stray from limiting my code (i.e. id much prefer to implement multiple form options). Anyway, thanks for the thoughts and ill respond back later on this weekend.

Comment: I suppose one way you could have multiple forms per action would be to define said forms with several subforms.  That way your pageController could check if the form has subforms, and if so, display each subform as its own form.  Then you may need to add an action to each subform so when `isPost()` is true, you can identify which subform should be validated.  Basically, each subform in the Zend_Form is really intended to be its own form.  Or instead of loading the form directly, you could load some helper class that had a getForm() method that would return a form or array of forms.